Find string in data
I am reading out an API interface to get an average price of a specific material.
The response of the API gives me a database including several different materials with a min and high price.
First I have to find the right material with the unique ID, which I implemented already. Afterwards I need to get the average price from the specific material, where I am stuck at the moment.
response = requests.get(test_url, params=test_params)

data = response.text

material_id = "<priceId>563</priceId>"

avg_price_list = []

#expected_output_value = "<priceNumber>min-high</priceNumber>"

if id in data:
    #find <priceNumber>min-high</priceNumber>
    # calculate average of both values
    # save value in a avg_price_list
else:
    print(id + " could not be found")

print(response.status_code)

#print(response.text)

API output:
    <Price>
  <priceId>541</priceId>
  <priceName>Yttrium Oxide</priceName>
  <priceSpec>99.999%min FOB China</priceSpec>
  <priceUnit>USD/kg</priceUnit>
  <priceNumber>7.6-7.7</priceNumber>
  <priceShowDateTime>2021-11-01</priceShowDateTime>
</Price>
<Price>
  <priceId>562</priceId>
  <priceName>Yttrium Oxide</priceName>
  <priceSpec>99.999%min In warehouse Rotterdam</priceSpec>
  <priceUnit>USD/kg</priceUnit>
  <priceNumber>8.2-8.4</priceNumber>
  <priceShowDateTime>2021-11-01</priceShowDateTime>
</Price>

